# May a stamp on a page "reserved for official entries" cause any issues?

Tags: passports, passport-stamps

Few days ago, when I was leaving Brazil, the border officer put the exit stamp on one of the "page reserved for official entries" instead of one of the "visas" pages. My passport is Polish.

May it be a problem in the future when using this passport? I'm not sure what "official use" means I'm this context, I understand it's reserved for use by the government.
[image: photo of the stamp]

Comment: What type of passport do you have? Is it an official passport?

Comment: @gstorto just a "standard" Polish passport, as described here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_passport

Comment: Apparently these pages are unique to Polish passports. They are used for amendments on name and civil status. I have just verified my Brazilian passport and no such pages exist. That is probably the reason the Brazilian official mistakenly stamped them. Only the Polish authorities can answer if your passport is still valid with a stamp on these pages.

Comment: It's not going to be an issue. You can ask the Polish authorities if you're paranoid.